# When running application A from the launcher it sometimes also runs application B

Tags: android, manifest

I have one Gallery application (A) that binds to a service. 
I have second transparent application (B) that just runs a service unbound and closes itself.
sometimes - when running application B from the launcher it also runs for a split of a second the application A. I see the layout of application A appears and disappear.
I suspect that something in the manifest is defined wrong : launchMode or taskaffinty. 
any ideas?

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name="com.temp.tempApp.GalleryActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:label="@string/app_label_gallery"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


       <activity android:name="com.temp.tempApp.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.temp.tempApp.MainService"  android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, one of the following fixed it:
1. add to each activity specific afinity value "android:taskAffinity="com.example.MainActivity""
2. different icons for the 2 activities.

hope it helps somebody in the future